# Trigonalizing a matrix problem.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

Let $A$ be a $3\times 3$ matrix defined by
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
3&-1& 1\\2 & 0 &1\\1&-1&2\end{pmatrix}$$

- Find the eigenvalues as well as the eigenspaces related to it.
- Prove that the matrix $A$ has a triangular form
  $$T=\begin{pmatrix}
  \lambda_1&m&0\\0 &\lambda_1 &0\\0&0&\lambda_2\end{pmatrix}$$
  where $m$ is a constant to be determined.

**My Attempt**
The eigenvalues are $\lambda_1=2$, and $\lambda_2=1$, with $\lambda_1$ having a double multiplicity (i.e $P(\lambda)=-(1-\lambda)(2-\lambda)^2$).

The spaces are
$$V_{\lambda_1}=Vect\{(1,1,0)^{\top}\}$$
$$V_{\lambda_2}=Vect\{(0,1,1)^{\top}\}$$
In all of my attempts, I tried to complete the basis with a canonical vector of $\mathbb R^3$. I tried $(1,0,0)^{\top}$, $(0,0,1)^{\top}$, and $(1,1,1)^{\top}$.

My problem is that at every single attempt, I get these two triangular matrices,
$$\begin{pmatrix}
2&0&1\\0 & 1 &0\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix},
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{pmatrix}
2&0&1\\0 & 1 &1\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix}
$$

I really don't understand what's wrong with my attempts, I thought I might've miscalculated the inverse, but turns out it's correct, with every basis completing. Probably that's the problem too.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: The first is not so bad, but you ought to reorder the eigenvalues. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Example:_Obtaining_the_normal_form) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector#Jordan_chains) for the method. The third vector is not random, you should consider $\ker (A-2I)^2$.

Comment: If you have chosen the ordered basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ to obtain the first matrix, then the basis $(v_1,v_3,v_2)$ will put it in the required form.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Merci bien ! It was the eigenvectors order all along.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $\lambda_{1}=2$,find a basis $\{f_{1}=(0,1,1);f_{2}\}$ for $V_{\lambda_{1}}^{*}=Ker(T-\lambda_{1})^{2}$,let $f_{3}=(1,1,0)$ ,wrt basis  $\{f_{1};f_{2};f_{3}\}$ the matrix has the desired form. Remark that you can always pick $m=1$ by replacing $f_{2}$ by $t f_{2}+ f_{1}$ for a suitable choice of $t$.

Comment: Exactly, I went on calculating as if the basis was complete for $\lambda_1=2$. Thank you Belkacem.